# Tomcat's performance stress-testing

Tags: java, performance, tomcat

I'm trying to make some load-tests with using Apache JMeter and different JVM/CATALINA options and got strange results.

How were tests prepared - using script-writer, visit web-application pages, run action (select in fields, select different pages etc).

After it - prepare Thread Group with 10 threads (users) with 1 sec rump-up period.

Each test with each new JVM parameters repeated 3 times. And here is very odd results - as better configuration was added to server.xml and/or JAVA_OPTS - then more worst results:

Columns here: XMS/XMX (in Gigabytes), Throughtput/Avarage

Using no compression, default Threads options:

```
1/2 4930/113
1/4 4850/115
4/4 4730/118
```

With maxThreads=500 and minSpareThrads=500, xms/xmx=4G:

```
4/4 4550/124
```

Same with compression=on:

```
4/4 4378/130
```

So, what I'm doing wrong? No any significant perforance increase, only some decrease...

Or - I'm doing wrong tests, or - incorrectly understanding JVM/CATALINA options..?

Answer (score 0):

Some questions come to mind:

- Are the client and the server on the same machine? If so, they may block each other
- If they are not, have you maxed out your network?
- What is the size of the payload?
- What is the logic within the tomcat? Does it rely on other party such as database? If so, can this be the problem?
- Have you ran it when a profiler is attached to the tomcat? It can help you identify what the code is actually doing.

Comment: 1) Tomcat have opts: CATALINA_OPTS="...-d64 -server", JAVA_OPTS - haven't "-client", in proccess - I see only "-server" - so I think - JVM for Tomcat run in "server" mode;

2) I don't checked it yet (but will look next time) - but don't think there is nework causes;

3) Can you please explain - what is "payload" here?

4) Yes, web-application uses Oracle DB on onother hosts, will check it, thanks;

5) Yep, but doesn't found anything unusual (like 100% CPU of Mem usage).

Comment: 1) The client here is JMeter; 3) payload is the size of the response